# Check if point is in convex polygon

Tags: math, lua, polygon, contains, convex

I'm trying to check if `point x, y` is inside of polygon `poly = {x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3 ...}`

But something goes wrong:

```lua
local function pointInConvexPolygon(x, y, poly)
    -- poly as {x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, ...}
    local imax = #poly

    local function isVerticesClockwise(poly)
        local sum = 0
        local imax = #poly
        local x1, y1 = poly[imax-1], poly[imax]
        for i = 1, imax - 1, 2 do
            local x2, y2 = poly[i], poly[i + 1]
            sum = sum + (x2 - x1) * (y2 + y1)
            x1, y1 = x2, y2 -- fixed
        end
        local isClockwise = sum < 0
        love.window.setTitle(isClockwise and 'clockwise' or 'counterclockwise')
        return isClockwise
    end

    local sign = isVerticesClockwise(poly) and 1 or -1
    local x1, y1 = poly[imax-1], poly[imax]
    for i = 1, imax - 1, 2 do
        local x2, y2 = poly[i], poly[i + 1]
        local dotProduct = (x - x1) * (y1 - y2) + (y - y1) * (x2 - x1)
        if sign * dotProduct < 0 then
            return false
        end
        x1, y1 = x2, y2
    end
    return true
end
```

Sometimes clockwise direction is right, but sometimes it says wrong direction.

Comment: `y1 - y2` vs `x2 - x1` doesn't look right. One of these is probably swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct formula of the triangle signed area is `(x1*y2 - x2*y1)/2` assuming the third vertex is at `(0,0)`
A point is inside a convex poly when all point-edge-traingle areas are of the same sign.

```
local function polyEdgeIterator(poly)
   -- poly as {x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, ...}
   local i, imax = 0, #poly
   local x2, y2 = poly[imax-1], poly[imax]
   return
      function()
         i = i + 2
         if i <= imax then
            local x1, y1 = x2, y2
            x2, y2 = poly[i - 1], poly[i]
            return x1, y1, x2, y2
         end
      end
end

local function getTriangleArea(x0,y0, x1,y1, x2,y2)
   -- area of the triangle, its sign is determined by the triangle vertices sequence direction (CW/CCW)
   return ((x1-x0) * (y2-y0) - (x2-x0) * (y1-y0)) * 0.5
end

local function pointInConvexPolygon(x, y, poly)
   local minArea, maxArea = 0, 0
   for x1,y1, x2,y2 in polyEdgeIterator(poly) do
      local area = getTriangleArea(x,y, x1,y1, x2,y2)
      minArea = math.min(minArea, area)
      maxArea = math.max(maxArea, area)
      if minArea * maxArea < 0 then
         return false
      end
   end
   return true
end

print(pointInConvexPolygon(2,1, {1,-1, 2,2, 4,1})) -- true
print(pointInConvexPolygon(3,0, {1,-1, 2,2, 4,1})) -- false
```

Comment: Is  multiplying by *0.5 in the triangle area necessary? I see that we need just sign, not value: 
local area = ((x1-x0) * (y2-y0) - (x2-x0) * (y1-y0))

Comment: @darkfrei - Yes, you can rename the function to `getTriangleDoubleArea`, it will not affect `pointInConvexPolygon`